# format of json encoded array

Tags: parsing, json

i have a json_encoded array which outputs the json like this

```
[Object {id="1", name="Muslin", image1="muslin.jpg"}, Object {id="72", name="damn", ...}]
```

Will it get parsed by jquery's parsejson 
If no then why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate json objects yourself  using  http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter

Json format should be as follows,

```
{
 "users": [
    { "id":"1" , "name":"Muslin", "image1": "muslin.jpg" },
    { "id":"72" , "name":"damn", "image1": "damn.jpg" }
        ]
}
```

Comment: it says invalid , whta do i do now as i am getting this output from php's json_encode