# jQuery JSON.parse: unexpected end of data

Tags: jquery, json, mongodb

I am having some noobist problems with jQuery on a simple example I try to run. The firefox tools give a `Syntax Error: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data` and I really can't find a way to debug it.

I have populated my mongodb with the data below and they do look verified.

```
var employees = [
    {"id": 1, "firstName": "James", "lastName": "King", "managerId": 0},
    {"id": 2, "firstName": "Julie", "lastName": "Taylor", "managerId": 1},
    {"id": 3, "firstName": "Eugene", "lastName": "Lee", "managerId": 1},
    {"id": 4, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Williams", "managerId": 1}
];
```

and I am trying to return it with

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
var name = req.query["name"];
    db.collection("employees", function(err, collection) {
        if (name) {
            collection.find({"fullName": new RegExp(name, "i")}).toArray(function(err, items) {
                console.log(items);
                res.jsonp(items);
            });
        } else {
            collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
                console.log(items);
                res.jsonp(items);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

and read it on the browser with

```
$.get("http://localhost:8888/employees",function(jsonp){
    //document.write("json");       
});
```

EDIT:
Using the url on the browser returns valid data, however, for the same action the console.log returns invalid data. This is what makes me suspect a double parsing issue, if there is anything like that.

```
browser-> { "id": 4, "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Williams", "managerId": 1, "_id": 5276247a3f2e4cf040000004 }
console-> { id: 4, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Williams', managerId: 1, _id: 5276247a3f2e4cf040000004 }
```

Comment: Use your browser or curl to verify that your script sends valid JSON to the client.

Comment: Can you validate/verify your json objects is seems correct? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631076/format-of-json-encoded-array/19631211#19631211

Comment: If i give the URL to the browser I get the correct and validated json records. I start thinking that there could be some kind of double parsing of the data. Could something like that be the issue?

Comment: I have tried both, however without really knowing the difference. Same result.

Comment: Use `res.json(items)` instead of `jsonp`.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I tried that too. Same results.

Comment: It's something else you're not showing then.

Comment: hm...could you be more specific? Any ideas about what I am missing? Do you need more info? :-)